# How to return TRUE if there was a record in the past 24 hours in R?

Tags: r, datetime

I'm rather new to R and I'm struggling with the solution to the problem. I have 2 datasets.

First is a transactions records per customer:

```
transactions <- dplyr::tibble(order_id = c(1,2,3),
                              customer_id = c(1,1,2),
                              order_date =c("01.02.2023 10:00:00","01.04.2023 10:00:00","01.02.2023 10:00:00"))
```

Second one is when customer received an email, customer can receive several emails between orders:

```
emails <- dplyr::tibble(email_id = c(1,2,3,4,5,6),
                        customer_id = c(1,1,1,1,2,2),
                        email_date =c("01.01.2023 10:00:00",
                                      "01.01.2023 12:00:00",
                                      "01.02.2023 08:00:00",
                                      "01.02.2023 09:00:00",
                                      "01.02.2023 10:00:00",
                                      "01.02.2023 11:00:00"))
```

I would like to add a column to the first dataset that will return TRUE if customer has received an email in the last 24 hours prior to the transaction.

| customer_id | order_id | order_date | email_last_24_hours |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 01.02.2023 10:00:00 | TRUE |
| 1 | 2 | 01.02.2023 09:00:00 | FALSE |

Comment: Please show what you tried, maybe you were on the right track.

Comment: Try to give a data example that illustrates your needs. Why is your email table so much larger, is that because many ID's did not place any order or perhaps are many users mailed many times? It totally makes a difference in the solution, for example the first is just a merge with all.x is true while in the second scenario you want for example join on the nearest match of email records and then check if those are less than 24h apart

Comment: Sorry for unclear question, I've edited it a bit and tried to recreate how data approximately looks like. And yes, it's a second scenario where customer can receive multiple emails between orders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make a test dataset:

```
transactions <- dplyr::tibble(customer_id = c(1,2),
                       order_date =c("01.02.2023 10:00:00","01.02.2023 10:00:00"))


emails <- dplyr::tibble(customer_id = c(1,1,2,2),
                 email_date =c("01.02.2023 09:00:00",
                               "01.07.2022 09:00:00",
                               "31.12.2022 09:00:00",
                               "11.10.2022 09:00:00"))

transactions$order_date <- lubridate::dmy_hms(transactions$order_date)
emails$email_date <- lubridate::dmy_hms(emails$email_date)
```

write the function that does what you want:

```
has_received_email <- function(customer_id, order_date, emails) {
  purrr::map2_lgl(customer_id, order_date, 
                  function(.customer_id, .order_date) {
                    
                    email_dates <- emails %>% 
                      dplyr::filter(customer_id == .customer_id) %>% 
                      dplyr::pull(email_date)
                    
                    any(difftime(.order_date, email_dates, units="hours")<=24)
                    
                  })
}
```

Use it to add a column to your transaction table:

```
transactions %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(received_email = has_received_email(customer_id, order_date, emails))
```

| customer_id | order_date | received_email |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-02-01 10:00:00 | TRUE |
| 2 | 2023-02-01 10:00:00 | FALSE |

or otherwise join, group and summarize:

```
dplyr::left_join(transactions, emails, by="customer_id") %>% 
  dplyr::group_by_at(all_of(names(transactions))) %>% 
  dplyr::summarize(received_email = any(difftime(order_date, email_date, units="hours")<=24))
```

Comment: Thank you! This solution seems to be working for me. I only added & difftime(.order_date, email_dates, units="hours")>=0 into function, since negative values also were returning TRUE.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `merge()` function in R to join the two datasets on the customer_id column. Then, you can use the `difftime()` function to calculate the time difference between the `email_date` and `order_date` columns. Finally, you can use an `ifelse()` statement to create a new column that returns "TRUE" if the time difference is less than or equal to 24 hours and "FALSE" otherwise.

```
# Load the two datasets
transactions <- read.csv("transactions.csv")
emails <- read.csv("emails.csv")

# Merge the datasets on customer_id
merged_data <- merge(transactions, emails, by="customer_id")

# Calculate time difference between email_date and order_date
merged_data$time_difference <- difftime(merged_data$order_date, merged_data$email_date, units="hours")

# Create a new column that returns TRUE if time difference is less than or equal to 24 hours
merged_data$email_last_24_hours <- ifelse(merged_data$time_difference <= 24, "TRUE", "FALSE")
```

or using lapply:

```js
transactions$email_last_24_hours <- lapply(transactions$customer_id, function(x){
  email_date <- emails[emails$customer_id == x, "email_date"]
  if(is.na(email_date) || difftime(transactions[transactions$customer_id == x, "order_date"], email_date, units="hours") > 24) {
    return("FALSE")
  } else {
    return("TRUE")
  }
})
```

Comment: Is it possible to do it without merging datasets? It was the first thing I've tried, but I'm working with relatively large datasets and even with smaller sample from this dataset after merging I got millions rows with a lot of duplicates (before merging first dataset has 90k rows, second with emails about 500k).

Comment: How about using lapply? See updated comment

Answer (score 0):

For this solution to truly shine, you should have a transaction ID too as well or at least something to identify an order per customer.

With `dplyr` and `lubridate` you can do

```
library(tidyverse)

df_1 %>% 
  left_join(df_2) %>% 
  mutate(
    emailed_24 = email_date %within% interval(order_date, order_date %m-% days(1))
  ) # Checking if email_date is within an interval, order_date - 24h (days(1))

# A tibble: 2 × 4
  customer_id order_date          email_date          emailed_24
        <dbl> <dttm>              <dttm>              <lgl>     
1           1 2023-02-01 10:00:00 2023-02-01 09:00:00 TRUE      
2           2 2023-02-01 10:00:00 2022-12-31 09:00:00 FALSE
```